# Python regex : trimming special characters

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, expression

Is it possible to remove special characters using regex?

I'm attempting to trim:

```
\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tButte County High School\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
```

down to:

```
Butte County High School
```

using

```
regexform = re.sub("[A-Z]+[a-z]+\s*",'', schoolstring)
print regexform
```

Comment: new to stackoverflow.. looking for an edit button for my original question.

Comment: Fixed. The 'n' is suppose to be '\n'

Answer (score 3):

You do not need regex for this simple task. Use [`string.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) instead. For example:

```
>>> my_string = '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tButte County High School\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
>>> my_string.strip()
'Butte County High School'
```

In case it is must to use `regex`, your expression should be:

```
>>> re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]\s+', '', my_string)
'Butte County High School'
```

It matches a string of characters that are not letters or numbers.

Comment: Those expressions won't strip a single leading or trailing space.

Comment: @anonymous you're right. But your regex won't work for ` Butte ` as Soviut pointed out.

Comment: @Soviut, Jean: It works: `>>> my_string = 'Butte  '; >>> re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]\s+', '', my_string)` prints `'Butte'`

Comment: It's pretty clear the OP is going to have to support more than just `[A-Za-z0-9]` if they're trying to trim school names, so the regex portion of this answer is going to fall apart quickly.

Comment: @Soviut: I agree, but I took into consideration *trimming special characters* as is mentioned by OP

Answer (score 1):

If you're really set on using regular expressions:

```
re.sub(r'^\s+|\s+$', '', schoolstring)
```

This will work for:

```
'   this is a test   '   # multiple leading and trailing spaces
' this is a test '       # one leading and trailing space
'this is a test'         # no leading or trailing spaces
'\t\tthis is a test\t\t' # leading or trailing whitespace characters
```

This expression one or more whitespace characters from the start `^\s+` of the string or `|` one or more whitespace characters from the end of the string `\s+$`.

However, `string.strip()` is simpler for removing leading and trailing space.

Comment: Yeah, I'm revising the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Except you have reasons to want to use regex, you can remove all edge white space with `.strip()` function in python